# C++: Count in specific column of 2d vector

Tags: c++

The following code counts how many times the string "CMO" occurs in the **nth row** of the 2d vector dataIn

```cpp
vector< vector<string> > dataIn ( nrows, vector<string> (ncolumns) );
int mycount = count(dataIn[n].begin(), dataIn[n].end(), "CMO");
```

Now, I would like to do the same thing, however, in the **nth column**. Can someone help me? I know, there are several ways to solve this problem by using *if* conditions and loops. However, my question is related to the InputIterators (InputIterator first, InputIterator last):

```cpp
count (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& val)
```

How do I have to set the InputIterators to consider only the nth column? The 2d vector is huge, this is the reason, why I don't want to check the entire 2d vector.

Comment: `std::count_if` and your lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is no such solution with *InputIterators*. Hence, here is the solution with *if* condition and *for* loop:

```cpp
unsigned int c = 0;
for(auto vec : dataIn) {
  if(vec[n] == "CMO") {
    c += 1;
  }
}
```